# Converting Ruby Hash into YAML for locales that already exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are lots of locales files on my application and they all are in `.rb` files using the Ruby Hash. What I want is simple: there is a way to convert them all into  `.yml` with no stress?

Can be an online converter (I already searched about it but without success) or even a Ruby trick.

### What I already have tried

For test proposals, I copied an entire code of a `.rb` and used `.to_yml` after that. The result? Inline scripting – in this case, there's something that can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not right a script in Ruby?

```
require "yaml"
File.write(destination_yaml_file, YAML.dump(eval(File.read(original_ruby_file))))
```

Comment: Your solution worked for me, but the real point was my bad. Everything that I needed was a `<pre>` tag to redesign codes on screen.